# Mean value by equality of rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following data (example)

```
# x y z
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 1 4
2 3 5
3 5 6
```

and need to eliminate the duplicates in the `x` and `y`.
To do it  and to not loose information, I will calculate the mean value of the last elements of the `array`, but only if the first and second columns are equal. For instance the result of the above example
should be

```
1 1 3  # mean of 2 and 4
1 2 3
2 3 5
3 5 6
```

As far I solved that in a very `unpythonic` way:

```
data = np.loadtxt('somefile') # 2D data
X = data[:, 0]
Y = data[:, 1]
x_new = []
y_new = []
z_new = []
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        new_data = data[np.logical_and(data[:, 0] == x, data[:, 1] == y)]
        if len(new_data) >= 2: # some duplicates here
            z_mean = np.mean(new_data[:, -1])
            x_new.append(x)
            y_new.append(y)
            z_new.append(z_mean)
```

My solution is very slow .. and ugly.
Is there some better way to solve this? `Pandas`?

EDIT: The example  may be misleading, then in this particular case `x` is equal to `y`. But the interesting case is of course, where the points `(x,y)` are duplicated.

Comment: What is type of `data` ?

Comment: Try using a data structure which supports "group by", then select x,y, mean z, group by x, y

Comment: What must be the output if the third row changes from `1 1 4` to `1 2 4`? Could you add expected output for such a case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use pandas and make `data` into a DataFrame , you can do this very easily with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) . Example -

```
newdf = df.groupby(['x','y']).mean().reset_index()
```

Demo -

```
In [186]: df
Out[186]:
   x  y  z
0  1  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  1  1  4
3  2  3  5
4  3  5  6

In [187]: newdf = df.groupby(['x','y']).mean().reset_index()

In [188]: newdf
Out[188]:
   x  y  z
0  1  1  3
1  1  2  3
2  2  3  5
3  3  5  6
```

---

If `x` / `y` / `z` are numpy arrays or list, then you can create the dataframe very easily using -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':xarray,'y':yarray,'z':zarray})
```

If `data` is a 2-D numpy array, you can do -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y','z'])
```

---

Just to give a clearer example, lets say the `data` is something like -

```
x y z
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
2 3 5
3 5 6
```

Then the result of above suggestion would be to group `(1,2)` and take mean of `3` and `4` which would be `3.5` .

Demo -

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   x  y  z
0  1  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  4
3  2  3  5
4  3  5  6

In [5]: newdf = df.groupby(['x','y']).mean().reset_index()

In [6]: newdf
Out[6]:
   x  y    z
0  1  1  2.0
1  1  2  3.5
2  2  3  5.0
3  3  5  6.0
```

Comment: Does it take care of the requirement - "only if the first and second columns are equal"?

Comment: Yes , as you can see from the example . I believe by that you mean both equal at the same time , and not equal to each other , equal to the other row's first and second column.

Comment: Yes, let's say the first row becomes `1 2 2` and the third row `1 2 4`, then we would have no rows with first and second elements being equal and thus, as per the question, there must be no grouping IIUC.

Comment: That is not the question , you can check the update from the op itself . He just is looking for duplicated values of (x,y) together , not x==y , x==y is never checked by OP's working code either . What OP wants is grouping , which is done in answer . If the changes you said occur , there there are three rows with x=1 and y=2 , and the z for all those rows are taken and mean found for the result